# How can I setState() and dispatch a redux action (including that state) in the same function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a class component in react with state like this:

```
state = {
numberOne: 1,
nunbmerTwo: 2,
sumOfThem: ''
}
```

I have a form with a submit function that set state of the component and dispatch a redux action..
Something like this:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDeafult();
this.setState({sumOfThem: this.state.numberOne + this.state.nunbmerTwo });
this.props.reduxAction(this.state)
}
```

When I try it like this, redux only recieve data from the first two states (the third is blank)
I have tried with try / catch / finally statements but the same thing is happening.

Is there a way to set the state of a component and dispatch it to redux both when submiting a form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `setState`'s callback function, which will be triggered once the component state gets updated. Below is the exmple.

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDeafult();
  this.setState(
    { sumOfThem: this.state.numberOne + this.state.nunbmerTwo },
    () => {
      this.props.reduxAction(this.state);
    }
  );
};
```

Below is the definition of `setState`. You can refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more info about the `updater` and the `callback`

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.